# How to copy a paragraph using keyboard keys in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to copy a paragraph in Selenium Webdriver in Java in Chrome. Basically, I am trying to select upper part of paragraph (starting from the center) by moving mouse cursor, hold control button, select the remaining part of the paragraph by moving mouse cursor, press "C", and release the control button. This used to work, but not anymore. The lower part of the paragraph is not being selected. My method is below:

```
void CopyParagraph(Actions build, WebDriver driver, String xpath, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)   {
//  Selects and copies paragraph from a web page using a web element as a reference point.
//  Receives  actions object, web driver, web element xpath as well as lower right hand corner and upper left hand corner x and y coordinates.

    WebElement start = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));

    build.dragAndDropBy(start, x1, y1).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).dragAndDropBy(start, x2, y2).sendKeys("c").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
    Action selectParagraph = build.build();
    selectParagraph.perform();
}
```

How can I copy a whole paragraph in Selenium Java?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on multiple different websites? Could you post an example minimal html or a link to a website to reproduce it?

Comment: I am trying to only do it on Selenium website for wikipedia (first paragraph):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium

Comment: you can use this trick,       keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)              and press Left or Right key to select your text

Comment: After I am running the following command:


  build.dragAndDropBy(start, x1, y1).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).keyDown(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("c").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).keyUp(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT);
  
I am getting the following error message:


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key Down / Up events only make sense for modifier keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath of paragraph and use gettext()

```
 WebElement start = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathofpara));
 CopiedPara=start .getText();
```

Comment: How would I used getText for a text box in https://pastebin.com/?

Comment: WebElement text=driver.findElement(By.id("paste_code")); and use send keys for e.g text.Sendkeys(CopiedPara);